# How to set spring library path in intelliJ idea

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am new to javeEE and spring. I have downloaded the spring libraries, apache common loggings api and apache tomcat.

I would like to set up a spring mvc framework project in intelliJ. I have the libraries, but intelliJ downloads them again every time I start a new project. I select libraries that it downloads, but now avail, it downloads the same libraries, plus adds my libraries into the "external libraries" tab in project structure.

I have set the `CLASSPATH` to the location of libraries by editing the `~/.bashrc` but still doesn't load the libraries.

How can I set the default spring framework library path for the intelliJ? I am using ubuntu 14.04 and Java version 1.8

Comment: May be better using maven (or other build tools) and write all lib in pom.xml as dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Just look for apache ivy, and a plugin for idea. With this you add any jar you want to your classpath